# If a constant variable is a type of function type, then what cannot be changed?

Tags: swift, function, variables, types

The code used here comes from the [Swift Official Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94)

```
func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var runningTotal = 0 

    func incrementer() -> Int {
        runningTotal += amount 
        return runningTotal
    }
    return incrementer
}

// what is the different with "var incrementByTen"
let incrementByTen = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)

// why there is a "()" ajacent to the variable name?
incrementByTen()
```

Variable `incrementByTen` is assigned with the function returned by `makeIncrementer` of with took the argument of 10.

**Question 1.** what's the differents when `increemtnByTen` is assigned to a variable instead of constant? Since here is constant, which part is unchangeable?

**Question 2.** Why the brackets pair "()" is used with the variable name when calling, I kind of knowing that this might be a function initializer staff. but `incrementByTen` is a constant name. Does it equal to the function it points to? Or this is just a general features of a programming language. When you want to use a variable/constant of a function type, you have to use "()" together with the name.

Comment: Hint: what type return function `makeIncrementer`?

Comment: @ShadowOf `makeIncrementer` function retrens a function type `() -> Int`. but the string `makeIncrementer` is a function name, it use the `()`. But string `incrementByTen` is a variable name how it can also use with '()'?

Comment: When you have function in variable, you need to have way to execute this function, right? This is the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Variable incrementByTen is assigned with the function

This is the key to everything. The value of `incrementByTen` is a function.

If `incrementByTen` were a `var` variable, then it could be reassigned to some other function. Since it's a `let` variable, it is a constant function. This is exactly identical to `var` and `let` variables of type `Int`. There is no deep difference between integer values and function values. They're just values.

The parentheses mean "call the function." `incrementByTen` is not the result of calling a function; it is the function itself. It is a value. When that value is evaluated, it returns a function. You can then call that function with the `()` operator.

This is exactly equivalent to:

```
makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)()
```

`makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)` returns a function, and `()` calls that function. This is analogous to:

```
let x = thingThatReturnsInt()
x + 10
```

In this case, `x` is an `Int` and we can apply the operator `+` to it. `makeIncrementer` just happens to return a `() -> Int` rather than an `Int`.

Comment: @Rob Napier Thanks so much. the explanation answered all my confusing regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `var` will work as well but is considered bad practice unless you need to modify the variable.
2. `incrementByTen` is a function of type `() -> Int`, since the function `makeIncrementer` returns another function.

Comment: 1. doesn't explain the difference 2. doesn't explain the role of `()`

Answer (score 1):

1. `let incrementByTen = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)` won't let you then do: `incrementByTen = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 42)`. The a new closure can't be reassigned to the variable unless it's changed to `var`.
2. `incrementByTen` is a closure type (`() -> Int`, to be specific). The `()` calls the closure with no arguements. In other words, `incrementByTen` is the closure itself (which will display `"(Function)"` when printed), whereas `incrementByTen()` is the `Int` value returned by calling the closure (which will display `10` when printed)

Comment: Hmm. the `let` firmly bond the value only to the function. Once it assigned it cannot be changed. Thanks for your explanation